# MySQL Sum and Update

Tags: mysql

Good Morning

I have a MySQL Table and it looks like this.

Table: Receiving

```
+--------------+-----------+---------+---------+-------+
| DateReceived | ItemCode  | QtyPack | QtyStan | PCS   |
+--------------+-----------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2016-09-09   | DRY000004 | 30.00   | 0.00    | 24.00 |
| 2016-09-09   | DRY000007 | 60.00   | 0.00    | 12.00 |
| 2016-09-09   | DRY000010 | 90.00   | 0.00    | 1.00  |
| 2016-09-09   | DRY000011 | 100.00  | 0.00    | 1.00  |
| 2016-09-09   | DRY000012 | 1.00    | 0.00    | 12.00 |
| 2016-09-09   | DRY000012 | 1.00    | 0.00    | 12.00 |
+--------------+-----------+---------+---------+-------+
```

and Table Variance

```
+-----------+-----------+
| ItemCode  | Receiving |
+-----------+-----------+
| DRY000004 |      NULL |
| DRY000007 |      NULL |
| DRY000010 |      NULL |
| DRY000011 |      NULL |
| DRY000012 |      NULL |
| DRY000013 |      NULL |
| DRY000014 |      NULL |
| DRY000016 |      NULL |
| DRY000017 |      NULL |
| DRY000018 |      NULL |
| DRY000019 |      NULL |
| DRY000020 |      NULL |
| DRY000021 |      NULL |
| EQU000001 |      NULL |
+-----------+-----------+
```

My Target here is to Get the Sum of `QtyPack` * `PCS` + `QtyStan` before transferring it in the column `Receiving` of Table : `Variance` and here is my code for that

```
UPDATE Variance VAR INNER JOIN receiving REv ON VAR.ItemCode = REV.ItemCode 
SET VAR.Receiving = replace(REV.QtyPack, ',', '') * replace(REV.PCS, ',', '') + replace(REV.QtyStan, ',', '')
WHERE VAR.ItemCode = REV.ItemCode and REV.Status = 'Posted' AND rev.DateReceived between '2016-09-09' and 
'2016-09-09';
```

Please disregard the Criteria in where clause but if you want to thats are my other criteria in `Table:Receiving`

even the code is working there seems something wrong I have a Data in Receiving that has the same `ItemCode` and that is `DRY000012` with `QtyPack` of `1`

To cut the story short here is my question

How can I sum all `ItemCode` before transferring it in Table `Variance`? For example `DRY000012` must become 24 before transferring in receiving.

TYSM for future help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE Variance t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ItemCode,
           Status,
           DateReceived,
           REPLACE(QtyPack, ',', '') * REPLACE(PCS, ',', '') +
           REPLACE(QtyStan, ',', '') AS amount
    FROM Receiving
) t2
    ON t1.ItemCode = t2.ItemCode
SET t1.Receiving = t2.amount
WHERE t2.Status = 'Posted' AND
      t2.DateReceived BETWEEN '2016-09-09' AND '2016-09-09'
```

This assumes that an `ItemCode` only appears once in the `Receiving` table, and that we don't need to any sort of aggregation before doing the `UPDATE`.

Comment: TYSM for help but I did some changes

Comment: Really great help, Approved